# Using Reactphp for sockets in PHP, port stops listening

Tags: php, sockets, reactphp

I'm developing an iOS app that has a chat system included (using these [instructions](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server)). The api runs on a LAMP server, so I used [ReactPhp](https://github.com/reactphp/socket) instead of [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) for python as socket handler to communicate between client/server and server/client.

This is the code I'm using for the file **socket.php**

```
<?
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$port = 1337;
$host = '127.0.0.1';

$app = function ($request, $response) {
    $response->writeHead(200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/plain'));
    $response->end('Hello '.time()."\n");
};

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$socket = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$http = new React\Http\Server($socket, $loop);

$http->on('request', $app);
echo 'Server running at http://'.$host.':'.$port."\n";

$socket->listen($port, $host);
$loop->run();
?>
```

Then I just run this on the terminal:

```
php socket.php
```

**The issues:**

1. It works fine, but... if I close the terminal (or stop the process with ctrl+Z), the port stops listening. How do I get the socket to listen all the time from the moment Apache starts?
2. After closing the terminal (case 1), if I try running `php socket.php` again, I get this message: **Could not bind to tcp://127.0.0.1:1337: Address already in use** - If the port is already in use, then why am I unable to access it after closing the terminal?

Comment: When you close the process, the ports will also close. try `nohup php socket.php` or google for `run php-cli in background`. For the second problem, catch the `SIGINT` signal and close the sockets before exiting the script.

Comment: Try the command bg after ctrl Z, ctrl Z HALTs the program

Answer (score 0):

What happens is, when you close the terminal session, you kill the process, **unless** you run it as a **daemon**.

[Nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) to the rescue!

From Wikipedia:

> nohup is a POSIX command to ignore the HUP (hangup) signal. The HUP
>   signal is, by convention, the way a terminal warns dependent processes
>   of logout.
>
> Output that would normally go to the terminal goes to a file called
>   nohup.out if it has not already been redirected.

If on Debian-based system (i.e. Ubuntu):

`sudo apt-get install nohup`

If on Fedora-based system (i.e. Centos):

`sudo yum install nohup`

Then, run your PHP script like this: 
`nohup php socket.php &`

This will **solve** your problem #1, which will in turn solve #2 as well.

If the process you just launched as a daemon writes anything to `stdout`, you can see that by running `cat nohup.out` from the folder where you executed the aforementioned `nohup php ...` command.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that php thread still running. From terminal:

```
ps -ef | grep php
```

Output:

```
501  7286  3848   0 10:09AM ttys002    0:00.08 php socket.php
```

Kill thread:

```
kill 7286
```

**Update for Nino:**
The second issue can happend using `nohup` command too.

Comment: That will fix his issue #2 after being caused by issue #1, but doesn't solve the real problem, which is issue #1.